# EF5: MySQL float value converts to Entity Single property - comma gets lost

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

Using DatabaseFirst aprroach with EF5, a `float` field in mySQL is converted to a `Single` property in the corresponding entity in the `DatabaseModel`. 
The comma information sometimes seems to get completely lost, for example:

- 1 (mySQL)   -> 1 (entity)
- 1,5 (mySQL) -> 15 (entity)
- 0,2 (mySQL) -> 2E+08 (entity)

In my database there are `item`'s produced by `tool`'s with certain `productiondata`'s. 
Therfor each `tool` has a collection of `productiondata`'s (1 to many). Also each `item` has a collection of `productiondata`'s (1 to many).
In my code there is one generic function that loads each database table into a `List<entity>` by eager loading.
`List<productiondata>` is ok.
`List<tool>` includes the collection `tool.productiondata` which is also ok.
`List<item>` includes the collection `item.productiondata` containing corrupt float values.
I cant see any reason why it works two times and once not, for all entities are loaded by the same function below ...

```
public void loadFromDatabase<TEntity>(ref List<TEntity> lst, List<string> lstCollectionNames) where TEntity : class
{
    using (var ctx = new techdbEntities1())
    {
        ctx.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

        IQueryable<TEntity> dbSet = ctx.Set<TEntity>();

        if (dbSet != null)
        {
            foreach (var collectionName in lstCollectionNames)
                dbSet = dbSet.Include(collectionName);  // 'Eager Loading'
            lst = dbSet.ToList<TEntity>();

            foreach (TEntity e in lst)                        
                ctx.Entry(e).State = EntityState.Unchanged;     // DBEntityEntry.State

            foreach (TEntity e in lst)
                e.GetType().GetProperty("State").SetValue(e, StateEnum.UnModified);     // TEntity.State
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment I can get the `productiondata` for a item from `List<productiondata>` instead of `item.productiondata` of `List<item>`, which solves the problem at the surface. 
But I am still very interested in the reason for the corrupt float fields.

Here is the sql:

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_productiondata_item1`    
FOREIGN KEY (`item_internalNr`)    
REFERENCES `techdb`.`item` (`internalNr`)    
ON DELETE NO ACTION  
ON UPDATE NO ACTION,  

CONSTRAINT `fk_productiondata_tool1`    
FOREIGN KEY (`tool_basetool_internalNr` , `tool_number`)    
REFERENCES `techdb`.`tool` (`basetool_internalNr` , `number`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION 
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Comment: Do you see any differences in the SQL queries? Also, what happens if you try EF6 and maybe another MySQL query provider?

Comment: Thanks, I posted my SQL above. And no, I did not try EF6 or another query provider for I do not want to change these things in a quite far stage of development.

Comment: I mean the queries for `List<productiondata>` and `List<tool>`. Are there any differences w.r.t. how the `productiondata` field is fetched?

Comment: I watched the SQL-strings the function loadFromDatabase() (see above) builds, but I cant see any difference concerning the collection productiondata.